# Open a local HTML File in a new window in Edge using Java

Tags: java

How to open a local HTML file in a new window in Edge? I tried the code below, but the HTML file opened in the same window in a different tab. I need to open the HTML file in a separate window. please do the needful

```
Process p = rt.exec("cmd.exe /C start \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe" C:\\MyView.html");
```

Comment: It sounds like you should look at the `msedge.exe` options when you start it from the command line. Maybe there is an option to have it start a new window? What you're currently doing, you should probably use [Desktop.browse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse(java.net.URI)) Although I don't think it will create a new window. It will also use your default browser and not necessarily edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is not a terminal emulator. You don't need `cmd.exe`. You can run `msedge.exe` directly.

I first searched Google for **microsoft edge command line options** which led me to:

[Get list of Edge command line switches](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/get-list-of-edge-command-line-switches/519d9efd-03df-4815-9cc7-b8f51d1bc932)

and that led me to:

[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

and that contained:

```
--new-window
```

So the minimal code required is:

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe",
                                       "--new-window",
                                       "C:\\MyView.html"); 
try {
    pb.start();
}
catch (IOException xIo) {
    xIo.printStackTrace();
}
```